# drawing chart with the help of google api

Tags: android

I am passing this url

```
String urlForLineChart ="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?" +
                "cht=lc&" +
                "chs=200x125&" +
                "chxl=0%3a|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10&"+
                "chd=t:10,3,5,8,15,20&"+                                
                "chxt=x,y&"+
                "chds=0,50&"+
                "chxr=0,0,16%7C1,0,50&"+
                "chm=s,FF0000,1,0,5";
```

To make a chart but it is not represent desired result kindly help me.
I am not getting that how to pass parameters. I searched a lot.

---

I am doing as follows

```
WebView mCharView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.char_view);
mCharView.loadUrl(urlForLineChart);
```

Comment: What's your desired result. Your URL [seems to generate a chart](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chxl=0%3a|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10&chd=t:10,3,5,8,15,20&chxt=x,y&chds=0,50&chxr=0,0,16%7C1,0,50&chm=s,FF0000,1,0,5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable Javascript in your webview:

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```